# Strange behavior with TableView separator when also using TableFooterView and row actions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here is a basic tableview that I have set up with a tableviewcontroller. The reuse identifier just gets a light green prototype cell.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 25)];
    [self.tableView.tableFooterView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:215/255 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1]];
}

- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewRowAction *removeFolderRowAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault
                                                                                 title:@"hi"
                                                                               handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                               {
                                                   return;
                                               }];

    return @[removeFolderRowAction];
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

@end
```

This produces this flow:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

where it starts with no bottom separator, then if you go to editing mode on the last cell there is still no bottom separator, but when done editing, a full width separator appears, which leaves if you go to editing mode again. If I were to have my tableFooterView be a view with frame CGRectZero, it would behave in the expected manner (there is a separator, same as all the other ones, that doesn't move when going to edit mode), however as soon as the tableFooterView has some height, it goes back to acting like the pictures above.

Comment: did you find the problem? i have this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i digged a bit and ios 11 fixed this issue for me. Seems to be a bug in previous versions.
For me the separator would show in the last rows that touch a header or a footer

Comment: Well ill accept this unless anyone comes in and posts about how to fix it in previous versions, but since its been 2 years i doubt it will happen.